# What do I use to fix down a shower tray?

Tags: shower, adhesive

I've tiled the floor of my new en-suite. I've bought a plastic shower tray, which says that it should be stuck down with adhesive.

Do I use normal grab adhesive? Or do I use tile adhesive?

I want to make sure the tray is well stuck down: it doesn't sit quite flat on the tiles so I plan on weighing it down at the ends while the adhesive cures, with the hope that when I take the weights off later it doesn't bend back up.

Comment: It may not be advisable to force the plastic tray into position and glue into place. Depending on the tray design, material properties and amount of forced displacement you may be inducing a long term stress that could result in tray failure. Your best bet is to connect with the tray manufacturer for advice.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - Thanks for your comment. I'm not worried about the stress; it's only a slight bend (due to being stored improperly) and straightening the tray doesn't require significant force. As for long term: over time stress from constant displacement decreases due to creep.